# Process is not getting command line arguments

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have .NET 3.5 C# Application which is running a second application with arguments.

It works well if I run the C# application with Visual Studio 2012 RC. But when I run the C# application via a shortcut or double-click on its .exe file it does not.

This is how I am starting the second application from my C# application:

```
serv = "100";
string cmd_args = " -nojoy -nomaster -nointro -game cstrike -appid 10 -gl -steam +connect 80.241.245.102:" + serv;
Process.Start(ucp_path, cmd_args);
```

The problem is that the second application is not getting the arguments that are passed to it from the C# application.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: the problem is `ucp_path` might not be an absolute path

Comment: path is full. Process starting without arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your arguments with quotes "\" [args] \"". Also check if the path is absolute.

Comment: string cmd_args = "\" -nojoy -nomaster -nointro -game cstrike -appid 10 -gl -steam +connect 80.241.245.102:" + serv + "\"";

Answer (score 0):

use `ProcessStartInfo`:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(filename, arguments));
```

Comment: Same result with ProcessStartInfo

Answer (score 0):

With your given info, the error couldn't be reproduced and the process receives all arguments correctly, whether it was started using parent program in VS or using parent ' exe (shortcut). Maybe the problem resides in the process code or more info is required to answer this question.